# How to automatically add an index to a table after a make-table query is run?

Tags: ms-access

I have an automatic process that runs some maketable queries in the morning and I'd like to apply some indexes to make queries faster. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177891(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: If the table structure is the same each day, then instead you could create your blank table, add the indexes you require, and then instead of re-creating the table each day, clear it out and re-insert the new data.